# Material UI make 2 elements the same height

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code:

```
<div className="center">
  <TextField
    variant="outlined"
    className="manualUserFollowTxt"
    required
    id="manualUserFollowTxt"
    label="Username"
    name="username"
    autoComplete="username"
    autoFocus
  />
  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className="manualUserFollowButton"
    onClick={(e) => this.followButtonClick(e, document.getElementById("manualUserFollowTxt").value)}
  > 
    Follow
  </Button>
</div>
```

Which basically results in:
[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGxy3.png)

What I want is to have the TextField and the Button be the same height with a little space in between and sitting on one line, preferably in the middle. Something like:

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w63w.png)

How can I achieve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the TextField and Button the same height and aligned, you can CSS [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on the parent div. 
Set the display to flex, and flex-direction to row. 
In order to apply spacing between the TextField and Button, you can apply margin-right to the TextField (here I used [material-ui styling](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#why-use-material-uis-styling-solution)):

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  textField: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },

}));

export default function TextFieldDemo() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
  <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <TextField
      variant="outlined"
      className={classes.textField}
      required
      id="manualUserFollowTxt"
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      autoComplete="username"
      autoFocus
    />
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className="manualUserFollowButton"
      onClick={(e) => this.followButtonClick(e, document.getElementById("manualUserFollowTxt").value)}
    > 
      Follow
    </Button>
</div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]